# Java regular expression dotall

Tags: java, regex

Until now I used this one:

```
"(?s).*\\(.*\\).*\\{.*\\}.*\\;.*"
```

I apply this on full request (so is multiline).
The problem is that it matches also when I have new lines between (){}; which I don't want. What I want to match is (){}; with any character inside this expression (except new lines), the new lines should be matched only before and after this expression.

So is there any way to specify only for one specific dot that it should match also new lines?

Comment: So put `[^\n]*` instead of `.*`?

Comment: @aioobe or insert `(?-s)` before the dot to turn dotall off. BTW it finally dawned on me what your name means - it's a classy name :)

Comment: @Bohemian, I assumed that he wanted the trailing `.*` to include new lines. (read your answer now, I had no idea you could turn it on or off mid expression! thanks for sharing that)  hehe, was it when coming up with a suitable variable name for an exception or did you scan my profile qr-code? ;-)

Comment: @aioobe it just came to me while I was thinking about something else - weird! btw - see my answer for how I addressed the trailing dot. Not elegant, but it is the first post I've made that employs a negative flag so i thought it worth it to show it in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert `(?-s)`, which turns DOTALL off, before the dot, then turn it back on again with another `(?s)`:

```
"(?s).*\\(.*\\).*\\{(?-s).*\\}(?s).*\\;.*"
```

Or much better, *temporarily* turn it off just for the expression (thanks to [@nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh) for this great suggestion!):

```
"(?s).*\\(.*\\).*\\{(?-s:.*)\\}.*\\;.*"
```

Comment: Another way: `"(?s).*\\(.*\\).*\\{(?-s:.*)\\}.*\\;.*"`

Comment: @nhahtdh awesome! I have added your much better solution to the answer (and attributed it to you too)

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove `?s`:

```
".*\\(.*\\).*\\{.*\\}.*\\;.*"
```

Or else use negation:

```
"(?s).*\\([^\\n]*\\).*\\{[^\\n]*\\}.*\\;.*"
```